# I have mistake in my gloox bot

Tags: c++, bots, chatroom, gloox

I have gloox Bot. I'm trying to create MUC room handler, but now I have mistake, when I compile it under gcc.

```
class MucHandler : public MUCRoomHandler {
private:
    Client *client;
public:
    MucHandler(Client *cl){
        client = cl;
    }

    virtual void handleMUCMessage (MUCRoom *room, const Message &msg, bool priv){
    }
    virtual bool handleMUCRoomCreation( MUCRoom *room )
    {
    }
    virtual void handleMUCSubject( MUCRoom * /*room*/, const std::string& nick, const std::string& subject )
    {
    }
    virtual void handleMUCInviteDecline(MUCRoom*, const JID& invitee, const string& reason){
    }
    virtual void handleMUCError(MUCRoom*, StanzaError error ){
    }
    virtual void handleMUCInfo( MUCRoom * /*room*/, int features, const std::string& name, const DataForm* infoForm )
    {
    }

    virtual void handleMUCItems( MUCRoom * /*room*/, const Disco::ItemList& items )
    {
    }
    virtual void handleMUCParticipantPresence(MUCRoom * room, const MUCRoomParticipant participant,Presence     presence){

    }   
};


class Bot {
private:
    Client *client;
    MUCRoom *room;
    MucHandler *muc;
public:
    Bot(string login, string password, string resource){
        const string fullJidName = login + '/' + resource;
        JID jid(fullJidName);
        //mucroom
        const string server = "conference.jabber.ru";
        const string uName = jid.username();
        const string roomJid = uName + "@" + server + "/" + uName;
        JID roomJID( roomJid );

        client = new Client(jid,password);
        client->setPresence( Presence::Available, -1 );

        //mucRoom handler 
        muc = new MucHandler(client);
        room = new MUCRoom( client, roomJID, muc, 0 );
        //room->registerMUCRoomHandler(muc);
        //

        client->connect();
    }
    ~Bot(){
        delete client;
        delete room;
    }

    void joinRoom(){
        room->join();
        room->getRoomInfo();
        room->getRoomItems();
    }

    void setRoomNick(const string& nick){
        room->setNick(nick);
    }
    void invite(const string& inv, const string& reason)
    {
        JID invitee(inv);
        room->invite(invitee, reason);
    }
};

int main(int argv, char** argc){
    Bot bot("example3@gmail.com","example3","home");
}
```

But I have mistake

cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Muchandler'
because the following virtual function are pure within 'MucHandler'
/usr/include/gloox/mucroomhandler.h:107: note virtual void gloox::MUCRoomHandler::handlerMUCParticipantPresence(gloox::MUCRoom*, gloox::MUCRoomParticipant, const gloox::Presence&)

I have no idea, how to fix it. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that there are pure virtual methods in `MUCRoomHandler` that you have not implemented in the derived class `MucHandler`. So, you have to implement them. You cannot instantiate an object with unimplemented member functions.

Specifically, it mentions this method from `MUCRoomHandler`:

```
virtual void handlerMUCParticipantPresence(MUCRoom*,
                                           MUCRoomParticipant, 
                                           const Presence&);
```

You have implemented this, which is different (look at the parameter list):

```
virtual void handleMUCParticipantPresence(MUCRoom * room, 
                                          const MUCRoomParticipant participant,
                                          Presence presence){ }
```

where I have removed the `gloox` namespaces for clarity.

Since your implementation of `handlerMUCParticipantPresence` has different argument types, it doesn't implement the pure virtual method. This is the source of the error.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of little differences between the code and the error message, so it's possible that this is  just a typo, but in the error message, `handlerMUCParticipantPresence()` takes a `Presence&` as a final argument, while the implementation you show just takes a `Presence` by value. If that's actually the case, then you haven't correctly overridden the pure virtual method, and so you can't  create an instance of your class.